# Check if gravatar exist with node.js

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, sails.js, gravatar

Hello right know I have a small web application using Sails.JS and I'm trying to set a default image if the user doesn't have a gravatar account/profile.

This is the code that I use to hash the email in my controller:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
req.session.email = 'user_email@gmail.com';
req.session.gravatar_hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(req.session.email).digest('hex');
```

As you see I have in session the hash  now.

So in my view I have:

```
<div class="gravatar" style="background-image: url('http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/<%=req.session.gravatar_hash%>?s=50');"></div>
```

This code works great for showing the gravatar (default or custom) image, but what If i want to do a validation so if the user doesn't have a gravatar I can use a custom image??
There is a way to validate that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Gravatar has you covered--they allow you to specify a default image URL to display if the user doesn't have a Gravatar.  From [their docs](https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/):

> If you'd prefer to use your own default image (perhaps your logo, a
>   funny face, whatever), then you can easily do so by supplying the URL
>   to an image in the d= or default= parameter. The URL should be
>   URL-encoded to ensure that it carries across correctly, for example:
>
> `<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/00000000000000000000000000000000?d=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fimages%2Favatar.jpg"/>`

[View the docs](https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/) for more options and info.

Answer (score 10):

You can check if a (HEAD) request to `'http://gravatar.com/avatar/' + req.session.gravatar_hash + '.png?d=404'` results in 404 or not.

Comment: I don't think Gravatar supports HEAD requests. This just times out for me: `curl --head 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e6ebbd9993d6b33b5fa08f809ed81b3c?d=404'`

Comment: @Jun-DaiBates-Kobashigawa You're missing the `.png` after the hash. The link still works for me.